# Codeigniter-3 Page Refresh doesn't load cache if cache path is set dynamicly

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I created an application where i want to give opportunity to switch to dark mode. I store the user choice in a cookie and i set the cache path according to it in my base Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       ...
       $this->config->set_item('cache_path', APPPATH . 'cache/' . (get_cookie('dark')?'dark':'bright') . '/');
   }
}
```

I have a Controller 'Item' with just a standard index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->output->cache(720);
    //business logic
    sleep(10);
}
```

Cache files are generated correctly and when i open the link site_url('item') the cache is loading (1 sec loading time). But when i hit F5 (Page Refresh) the page loading takes as long as if no cache was loaded (10 sec).

How do i load the cache correctly if the cache_path is set dynamicaly?